# Is the moderator diamond (♦) part of your username?

Tags: discussion, moderators, display-names

I noticed an [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5480) referring to a diamond moderator by username, and  the ♦ was included as if it were part of the username rather than a separate symbol. I was going to edit the post to remove it, but I wasn't sure: maybe that *is* part of the username, just like the "Dr." honorific is a real part of a doctor's name. Should I regard the symbol as part of the username when quoting someone myself?

Comment: SE team is currently discussing ways to put diamond sign into driver licenses of moderators

Comment: gerrit probably just copy pasted the mod's username from their user card. When doing that, is easier (and faster) to include the diamond (copying the displayed username from end to end, in one swift motion).

Comment: Not only it's not part of the user name, but diamond is also banned from being used in a display name. Try and see! ;)

Comment: (+1) Similar question [in jest]: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55465/5323

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not part of the username.

You can tell this by going to any moderators' user profile.

For example, https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9 
Notice the above link is not https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9♦

When you're on the profile page of a moderator, you'll notice it says their name :
ex: Shog9 *(then moderator ♦)*

When you go to the moderators user page, which lists all the mods for a site, https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators, you'll see that the diamond is not underlined when you hover, only the name.

So it's not part of the name, but you're free to include it when referencing a moderator in a post or comment, just out of respect or whatever.

Comment: Apparently the link with a diamond works as well: [Shog9♦](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9♦) ;)

Comment: @Hjulle That's because it really doesn't matter what username is there, just the user number. This works: [♦9gohs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/♦9gohs)

Answer (score 12):

No, the diamond is a decoration, not part of the name.  Somebody was probably just being cute -- either that or cut/pasted and picked up more than just the strict name.

You can confirm this by starting to ping a moderator in a comment or in chat -- the name completion after the `@` does not include the diamond.  (You'd also be able to see it in the "edit profile" interface, except you'd have to be a mod to do that so that doesn't help many people.)

Answer (score 4):

The diamond is attached to the end of the username when displayed by the system. This includes the top navigation bar, user pages, and the user card below each post. The diamond in the post was added by the poster.

However, I'm not sure why you'd remove it. The diamond easily communicates that the user is a site moderator, and removing it would not only eliminate that communicative element but would also be a minor edit, bumping a post to the top needlessly.

It's common for users to do this in meta discussions, and I've never seen it be a problem.